# Zurb Foundation 4 - Stick Top Bar weird behaviour?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm learning Zurb Foundation, so this is my first web site attempt. I have a problem with the Stick Top Bar. It "kind of" works, but it does some strange things when collapsed (all my items collapse into the button menu == small screen/window).

The problem is that if I go to the bottom of the page and I click on the "Menu" button on the top bar (on a small screen/window), the page goes to the top. My english is not the best, so I'll live this preview of the webpage so you can check it out:

http://okgo.comuv.com/

Steps to reproduce:
1) Resize your browser window until the topbar becomes collapsed (mobile version of the topbar).
2) Scroll down to the bottom.
3) Click "menu".

I've tried removing almost everything on the page, but the problem still persists.

Here's the code so you can take a look at it:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Beyond The Sky</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />

    <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%
    }

    #homepage {
        background-color: black;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-image: url(img/nasabackground.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        background-color: black;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-image: url(img/stars.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }

    #homepagecontentwrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: table;
    }

    #maintitlewrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #maintitle {
        color: black;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    .centertext {
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="homepage">
        <div id="homepagecontentwrapper">
            <div id="maintitlewrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <h1 id="maintitle">Hello There!<br/>This is a great site. Don't you think?</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-2 small-6 columns centertext">
                        <a href="#" class="button">Contacto</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 small-6 columns centertext">
                        <a href="#" class="button">Nosotros</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-8 hide-for-small columns">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
        <nav class="top-bar">
                <ul class="title-area">
                    <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">Beyond The Sky</a></h1></li>
                    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                </ul>

            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="left">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
    </div>

     <!--Content Placeholder--> 
    <div id="content">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <!--End of Content Placeholder--> 


    <script>
        document.write('<script src=' +
        ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
        '.js><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```